# Expected Value and Variance of Asymmetric Random Walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

let X be the step of an asymmetric random walk\begin{equation}
    X =
    \left|
        \begin{array}{cc}
                1 &  p \\
                -1 &  1-p \\
        \end{array} 
    \right.
\end{equation}
Let $Y_n$ be the position after $n$ steps. I am trying to prove $$E(Y)=n(2p-1)$$ and $$V(Y)=4np(1-p)$$

Solution:
$$Y = \Sigma^n X_i$$ so clearly $$E(Y) = nE(X) = n(2p-1)$$ Next I attempt to use $$V(Y)= E(Y^2) - E^2(Y)$$

$$Y^2=(\Sigma^n X_i)^2$$ so then $$Y^2 = \Sigma^n X_i^2 + 2\Sigma_{i \neq j}^n X_iX_j$$ and $$E(Y^2) = nE(X^2) + 2nE^2(X)$$ And $$E(X^2) =1 \ and \ E^2(X)=(2p-1)^2$$ Finally $$V(Y)=n +2n(2p-1) - n^2(2p-1)^2$$ Thus $$V(Y)\neq4np(1-p)$$ Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: When you write $V(Y)$ do you mean $Var(Y)$? Also your notation seems slightly off. You should usually state that you have a seqeunce of i.i.d random variables $\{ 
X_k \}$ such that $X_k\sim X$, and you define $Y_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$. Is this the case?

Comment: The environment to use in your first displayed equation is `cases`. Thus `X=\begin{cases}1&p\\-1&1-p\end{cases}` yields

$$
X=\begin{cases}1&p\\-1&1-p\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The number of pairs $(i,j)$ with $i \neq j$ ($1\leq i,j \leq n$) is $\binom {n } {2}=\frac {n(n-1)} 2$. So the second term in $EY^{2}$ is $n(n-1)(2p-1)^{2}$.

With this change you will get $V(Y)=4np(1-p)$.